# MS-DOS загрузочный сектор исходный код

Tags: ассемблер

В исходном коде MSDOS есть такая строка MASM:

```
ASSUME  ES:CODE
```

т.е. es = 07C0h куда и загружен boot sector при помощи bios компьютера. Далее есть код загрузки IO.SYS в память по адресу es:bx:

```
DoLoad:
mov BX,700          ;offset of ibmbio(IBMLOAD) to be loaded.
mov CX,3            ;# of sectors to read.
```

и после загрузки IO.SYS в память, как из кода понятно по адресу 07c0h:0700h в коде загрузчика делается прыжок:

```
jmp     far ptr 70h:0       ;CRANK UP THE DOS
```

Этот код предоставлен на MASM, я пишу загрузчик DOS на NASM. Вопрос, почему IO.SYS грузиться по адресу 07c0h:0700h а управление на IO.SYS передается на адрес 70h:0

И второй вопрос, IO.SYS на диске занимает больше 40,000 байт, а во время чтения с диска в память читается всего 3 сектора IO.SYS а это меньше чем размер IO.SYS на диске, почему?

Answer (score 2):

> т.е. es = 07C0h куда и загружен boot sector при помощи bios компьютера.

Вы что-то путаете..
Когда указывается `ASSUME ES:CODE`, то определяющий сегмент-кода регистр `CS=0`, и соответственно получается `ES=0`. Это потому, что перед тем-как передать управление загрузчику ОС, биос заносит в пару `CS:IP` значения `0000:7C00h`.

> Вопрос, почему IO.SYS грузиться по адресу 07c0h:0700h а управление на IO.SYS передается на адрес 70h:0

Таким образом IO.SYS грузится по адресу `0000:0700h`, но в силу того-что сегментные адреса считаются логическими, он совпадает с адресом `0070:0000h`. В этом можно убедиться, если запросить данные регионы памяти в отладчике. Как видим, дампы одинаковы:

```
C:\ debug
-d 0:0700
0000:0700  E9 6D 03 A7 00 EA FD 02-70 00 00 00 00 FF AF 00   .m......p.......
0000:0710  D9 02 87 DB 00 32 00 00-7E 03 A7 00 00 00 00 00   .....2..~.......
0000:0720  00 00 E8 00 36 00 70 00-13 80 EC 01 F7 01 43 4F   ....6.p.......CO
0000:0730  4E 20 20 20 20 20 48 00-70 00 00 80 EC 01 18 02   N     H.p.......
0000:0740  41 55 58 20 20 20 20 20-5A 00 70 00 C0 A8 EC 01   AUX     Z.p.....
0000:0750  FC 01 50 52 4E 20 20 20-20 20 6C 00 70 00 08 80   ..PRN     l.p...
0000:0760  EC 01 30 02 43 4C 4F 43-4B 24 20 20 7E 00 70 00   ..0.CLOCK$  ~.p.
0000:0770  00 80 EC 01 18 02 43 4F-4D 31 20 20 20 20 90 00   ......COM1    ..

-d 70:0
0070:0000  E9 6D 03 A7 00 EA FD 02-70 00 00 00 00 FF AF 00   .m......p.......
0070:0010  D9 02 87 DB 00 32 00 00-7E 03 A7 00 00 00 00 00   .....2..~.......
0070:0020  00 00 E8 00 36 00 70 00-13 80 EC 01 F7 01 43 4F   ....6.p.......CO
0070:0030  4E 20 20 20 20 20 48 00-70 00 00 80 EC 01 18 02   N     H.p.......
0070:0040  41 55 58 20 20 20 20 20-5A 00 70 00 C0 A8 EC 01   AUX     Z.p.....
0070:0050  FC 01 50 52 4E 20 20 20-20 20 6C 00 70 00 08 80   ..PRN     l.p...
0070:0060  EC 01 30 02 43 4C 4F 43-4B 24 20 20 7E 00 70 00   ..0.CLOCK$  ~.p.
0070:0070  00 80 EC 01 18 02 43 4F-4D 31 20 20 20 20 90 00   ......COM1    ..
```

> И второй вопрос, IO.SYS на диске занимает больше 40,000 байт, а во время чтения с диска в память читается всего 3 сектора IO.SYS а это меньше чем размер IO.SYS на диске, почему?

Расположенный по адресу `0000:7С00h` код загрузчика ОС проверяет наличие на диске системы DOS. Для этого считывается первый сектор корневого каталога и определяется наличие двух файлов - IO.SYS и MSDOS.SYS. Если оба файла найдены, то загрузчик считывает их в память и передаёт управление на точку входа модуля IO.SYS.

Загруженный с диска в память файл IO.SYS состоит из двух отдельных модулей:

• Модуль **"BIOS"** - содержит набор резидентных драйверов для устройств CON, COM, KEYB, TIMER, и т.д.

• Модуль **"SYSINIT"** - вызывается подпрограммой инициализации BIOS. Код этого модуля вычисляет размер непрерывной памяти ОЗУ, после чего копирует себя по её старшим адресам. Далее модуль переносит ядро системы MSDOS.SYS из области её начальной загрузки, в область окончательного расположения в памяти, и передаёт управление на точку-входа в MSDOS.SYS.

Видимо поэтому с диска читается только 3-сектора, которые представляют собой модуль "SYSINIT", а драйвера из модуля "BIOS" подтягиваются в память позже, на финальном этапе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Перед jmp на код IO.SYS нужно загрузить регистры, я загружаю mov bx, 21h потом делаю jmp на IO.SYS, вопрос - корректно ли это значение 21h - это в десятичной системе 33 - первый сектор данных диска.

Comment: `mov bx,21h` это параметр какого-то прерывания что ли? Зачем вы загружаете регистры?

Comment: IO.SYS требует инициализации регистров, 21h это 33 в десятичной это первый сектор данных диска где расположен IO.SYS. Вот исходный код загрузчика MS-DOS:
```
DISKOK:
mov CH,MediaByte
mov DL,BootDrv
mov BX,[BiosLow]  ; J.K.I1.Get bios sector in bx
mov AX,[BiosHigh]  ; J.K.I1.
jmp FAR PTR 70h:0  ;CRANK UP THE DOS
```

Comment: `>> 33 в десятичной это первый сектор данных диска где расположен IO.SYS` - во первых с сектора(33) начинаются разделы только у "Fixed" дисков (HDD/FDD), а если диск имеет тип "Removable" (USB-Flash), то у них раздел начинается с сектора(63). Поэтому значение в `BX` зависит от того, где находится у вас MS-DOS - на дискете Floppy, или на флешке. Во-вторых, в секторе(33) FAT всегда лежит структура ```BPB``` "Bios-Parametr-Block", а уже в ней прописывается указатель на номер сектора с данными, от куда и можно будет считать файл "IO.SYS".

Comment: Можете установить себе двоичный редактор "WinHex", который способен работать с дисками. Откройте в нём свой накопитель с установленной системой DOS и посмотрите, что лежит в том или ином секторе. То-есть сначала соберите базовую информацию в блокноте, а потом уже пишите код.

Comment: Спасибо. Я хочу уточнить. Например, в коде у меня есть: ASSUME  ES:CODE и это означает что ES = 0. А затем у меня есть BX = 700h. И эти два регистра составляют адрес 0000h:0700h от начала всей памяти ПК. То есть смещение 0700h от нулевого адреса всей памяти ПК. Я прав?

Comment: Да, всё верно..